# how to make shiny figures for cake decoration?

Tags: baking, cake, decorating

I am wondering how are the little figures on this [cute cake](https://instagram.com/p/4Rgs3LBQLQ/) are made? Whats the material and where can you buy molds and casts to shape them? and how are they so shiny?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These figures are probably made with [fondant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fondant_icing).

I think the figures are handshaped. There are [plenty of tutorials](https://www.pinterest.com/search/pins/?q=fondant+figures+tutorial). You can even look for [tutorials working with modelling clay](https://www.pinterest.com/search/pins/?q=modelling%20clay%20tutorial). 
Basically you only need a rolling pin, a knife and tweezers. Cans, forks, any food-safe utensil that has an interesting pattern are useful. Of course there are special molds for fondant but I don't think that you need them unless you want to make fancy things like [laces](https://youtu.be/rKWBiyAUEBk?t=11m45s). You can buy molds online but also in some larger hardware stores, supermarktes, or gift shops. It depends on where you are located.

Fondant is quite matt. [To make fondant shiny](http://www.craftsy.com/blog/2013/08/how-to-make-fondant-shiny/) you can

1. hold the fondant over steam or
2. apply shortening,
3. egg whites,
4. corn syrup, or
5. alcohol on the surface

Comment: Thanks @Ching Chong, I did not know there are techniques to make fondant shiny, all I had seen was kind of matt.

Comment: BTW,  , can you tell me what is the icing on the cake? (butter milk? cream? ) @Ching Chong

Comment: @fetah It's probably an ising that that has a low water content like [(American) buttercream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buttercream#Types). If you use other icings like cream cheese icings or normal whipped cream the fondant will melt.

Answer (score 4):

Ching Chong's answer is already very good. But note that everybody he said can also apply to marzipan figurines, not only fondant ones. This may increase your options, since I think marzipan is somewhat easier to shape.

Comment: thanks @rumstscho, I will try marzipan as well, although I don't like the taste

Comment: I totally agree with you, but in this case the figurines probably aren't marzipan, which is always slightly "grainy".